# Failed to find provider info for package

Tags: android, android-activity, package, provider

I'm not using any provider in my application, however i'm getting the error:

```
05-20 13:48:08.695    5003-5136/com.example.myapp E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.example.myapp
```

This error doesn't break the app but its strange because it show only my application package without a class, and the problem occurs only in samsung galaxy y duos...

Could it be any other app? A library in project?

This is bothering me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, was the MobileAppTracking API in the method trackAction. At least this doesn't break the app, but is a weird message in the log...